Normal Solvable Group
Prove that if H and K are two solvable normal subgroup of G then HK is also solvable normal subgroup of G.
I proved that every (H i  K  i ) is a normal subgroup of (H i+1  K  i+1 ) but now  I am struck in proving that Factors of Normal series of HK are abelian

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39814/for-g-a-group-and-h-unlhd-g-then-g-is-solvable-iff-h-and-g-h-are-solv and others that can be found by using site search within one minute.

And also here, and here.

While equivalent, the first linked question doesn't immediately appear to be the same, so I can understand OPs missing that.
I don't see a solution to the second, so while it is a duplicate, it doesn't help OP.
I agree we should avoid duplicates.

This question is a popular one, so it is not surprising, that it has been answered often. Sometimes one has to read the answers, to see this. Here the "key" is to see that $AB/B\cong A/(A\cap B)$ is solvable, and $B$ is solvable, hence $AB$ is solvable. This is the argument in many answers (see the duplicates).
